# This is about relations on sets

Tags: set

Definition : A relation on set S and T is any subset of the Cartesian product S x T.

Example:

The "larger than" relation for real numbers is the set:
L = {(x, y) | x, y E R, x > y}

Here the part I don't understand it says :

"Here S and T both equal R".

What does it mean?
The elements of set S is equal R and also the elements of set T is eqaul to R.
so S and T is also equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The elements of set S is equal R and also the elements of set T is eqaul to R. so S and T is also equal?
```

Exactly. As both x and y are real numbers, they are taken from the very same set, therefore they are sharing the same domain.

Comment: You are welcome, I wish you good luck in studying set-theory, that is a really beautiful and important topic.